# How to fix boot time of ubuntu 20.04 on hp

Tags: boot, 20.04, hp

My HP laptop normally takes around 2 minutes to appear on password screen after pressing the power key. It is becoming very frustrating for me. I have a decent specifications with core i7 7200U CPU and 16GB RAM with a HDD. I have followed every previous QA related to boot time but it is not helping on my context. What may be the problems and What can be working solutions?
The below is my log for `systemd-analyze blame`

```
1min 25.028s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                    
 28.577s snapd.service                                                 
 20.986s postgresql@12-main.service                                    
 19.090s fwupd.service                                                 
 16.662s networkd-dispatcher.service                                   
 15.101s systemd-journal-flush.service                                 
 13.435s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                            
 13.378s dev-sda2.device                                               
 12.126s tor@default.service                                           
  8.740s accounts-daemon.service                                       
  8.299s udisks2.service                                               
  7.598s redis-server.service                                          
  7.043s dev-loop10.device                                             
  6.454s dev-loop17.device                                             
  6.305s systemd-resolved.service                                      
  6.240s dev-loop15.device                                             
  6.211s dev-loop19.device                                             
  6.123s dev-loop20.device                                             
  5.715s dev-loop14.device                                             
  5.643s dev-loop12.device                                             
  5.586s bolt.service                                                  
  5.533s ModemManager.service                                          
  5.513s dev-loop6.device                                              
  5.471s dev-loop16.device                                             
  5.451s dev-loop11.device                                             
  5.310s dev-loop4.device                                              
  5.216s NetworkManager.service                                        
  5.215s dev-loop18.device                                             
  4.488s polkit.service                                                
  4.044s gdm.service                                                   
  3.710s dev-loop8.device                                              
  3.620s systemd-logind.service                                        
  3.620s dev-loop9.device                                              
  3.399s bluetooth.service                                             
  3.398s avahi-daemon.service                                          
  3.311s dev-loop0.device                                              
  3.310s dev-loop1.device                                              
  3.308s dev-loop3.device                                              
  3.307s dev-loop5.device                                              
  2.874s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                  
  2.848s thermald.service                                              
  2.836s switcheroo-control.service                                    
  2.825s wpa_supplicant.service                                        
  2.820s systemd-modules-load.service                                  
  2.799s gpu-manager.service                                           
  2.544s grub-common.service                                           
  2.490s dev-loop7.device                                              
  2.480s dev-loop2.device                                              
  1.851s apport.service                                                
  1.338s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C837\x2dBD59.service         
  1.226s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service           
  1.199s snap-code-33.mount                                            
  1.198s snap-core-9066.mount                                          
  1.141s snap-core-9289.mount                                          
  1.139s snap-core18-1705.mount                                        
  1.138s snap-core18-1754.mount                                        
  1.060s snapd.apparmor.service                                        
   951ms upower.service                                                
   851ms snap-docker-443.mount                                         
   822ms systemd-rfkill.service                                        
   806ms snap-docker-461.mount                                         
   766ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-33.mount                        
   765ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount                        
   764ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                       
   758ms systemd-udevd.service                                         
   725ms apparmor.service                                              
   717ms systemd-random-seed.service                                   
   716ms secureboot-db.service                                         
   668ms swapfile.swap                                                 
   664ms rsyslog.service
```

Comment: If you already tried all possible solutions, then you are unlaucky and the problem can't be fixed ;-)

Comment: See what's the cause of your slow boot via "systemd-analyze blame " . It might be apt-daily.service or snapd-seeded.service or something like that . Then if you really don't need that service , you can disable it via "sudo systemctl disable service_name " to improve your boot time.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi plymouth-quit-wait.service is taking 1 min 25s and snapd.service is around 30 seconds. Can I disable these?

Comment: @Bibek No. those times are relative . In fact snapd.service took around 57 seconds to start . So that's the problem . If you don't want to use snap programs , you can temporarily disable the snapd service via "sudo systemctl disable snap* ". And then reboot to see the changes.

Comment: The plymouth services simply wait that other services stops their tasks. So it's not plymouth that is slow, they are the other services that make plymouth to wait too long.

Comment: And also another redundant service is NetworkManager-wait-online.service  . If you don't boot your OS from network , you can safely disable it.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi It got reduced around 30 seconds Can you list those services which aren't needed during bootup. Is the dev loops necessary

Comment: @Bibek There are many more . Some of them could be easily started after you booted your system , for example you can start PostgreSQL server once you need it via "sudo service postgresql start ". It would gain you around 8 seconds  . If you don't use any ThunderBolt device you can disable bolt.service but you wouldn't gain so much . I don't know where are those "dev-loop.device"s come from , but I think it's somehow related to snap. But not sure whether it's safe to disable them.